# Are File* and Char* the same or is there a difference?

Tags: c, pointers

When I learned about pointers learned that `char*` was the operator for pointers but when I look at tutorials online I see people use `file*`. So I'm wondering if there a reason to use one over the other.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: They probably are not the same. Although it would help if you specify the language.

Comment: I am working in C language

Comment: What you should have learned is that `*` is the operator for pointers.  You can have pointers to any different type: `int *` for pointer to int, `char *` for pointer to char, etc.

Comment: C is case-sensitive. You probably mean `FILE*`, not `File*` or `file*`, and `char*`, not `Char*`. On the other hand, `File` and `Char` are valid identifiers, but they don't mean anything unless you define them yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C `FILE*` and `char*` are two completely different things.

`FILE*` is a pointer to a `FILE` structure which represents a file opened with something like `fopen`. There's a whole family of `f` functions that interact with these, like `fread` and `fclose`.

`char*` is a pointer to characters, which is to say in C terms, a "string" or a "buffer". The `str` family of functions deal with these, like `strncpy` and `strcmp` and such.

These are in no way similar except that they're both pointers, but given that you're talking about C, pointers are basically the C philosophy and are omnipresent.

Now C is considered a *strongly typed* language which means that any given function has extremely specific expectations for arguments and return type. If you try and supply a `FILE*` pointer to a function expecting `char*` you'll get a compile error. They're not compatible, and not interchangeable.

Comment: `strncpy` is a very poor example of a string function. Just to avoid confusion, you might consider changing that to `strcpy`.

Comment: Nit: a `char *` is not a *string*.  It may point to the first character of a string, or it may point to the first of a sequence of characters that do not make a string, or it may point to a single character that isn’t part of a larger sequence.  Yes, when we work with strings, we’re usually working with `char *` expressions, but that doesn’t mean a `char *` *is* a string.

Comment: @JohnBode That's why I said it could be a buffer as well, something that may not necessarily be a string but is absolutely composed of characters, at least as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Strictly speaking `FILE` is an opaque type - it could be anything.  One possibility is a data structure.    It could be anything through.

Comment: The two pointers could even have completely different representations, including size and alignment.

Comment: "*`char*` is a pointer to characters*" one "*s*" too much here. To point to multiple character***s*** one would use a pointer to an array of `char`, to a `char[]`, a pointer type like `(char*)[42]`, which obviously is different from "just" `char*`. A `char`*` points to one and only one `char`.

Comment: @alk Except when you do `char* x = &y` and then later `x[1]` where you can reference arbitrary characters relative to that location. The one-vs-many ambiguity here comes about because arrays and pointers in C have an entangled relationship. Yes, technically it is a pointer to a single character but in practice it represents the start of one or more characters.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers in C point to a particular type.  A `char *` is **not** the same as a `FILE *`.

So a `char *` is a pointer to a `char`, a `FILE *` is a pointer to a `FILE`, etc.  You would use whichever one is appropriate for what you're pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

> When I learned about pointers learned that char* was the operator for pointers

The symbol that indicates that a variable is a pointer is just the `*`. You can use this symbol to declare many different kinds of pointers. For example, `char*`is a pointer to `char`. and `FILE*` is a pointer to `FILE`. As other's have answered, these both have completely different uses.

Answer (score 0):

> When I learned about pointers learned that `char*` was the operator for pointers but when I look at tutorials online I see people use `file*`.

`char*` (more often spelled `char *`) is not an operator, it is a *type*.  Specifically, it is the type of a pointer to a `char` (usually, but not necessarily, the first in an array of them).  Provided that `file` is defined as a type, `file*` is also a type: the type of a pointer to a `file` (but did you mean `FILE`?).  These two pointer types are different and not interchangeable, though you can convert between them.

> So I'm wondering if there a reason to use one over the other.

Absolutely!  You use a `char *` when you want a pointer to `char`, and `file *` when you want a pointer to a `file`.  The former is the type by which C strings are handled, among other things.  `file` is not a built-in type, so I could only speculate what it or the pointer type derived from it might be used for, but certainly not the same things that a `char *` would be used for.

Answer (score 0):

char * means pointer to something of type signed character.
FILE * or file * means pointer to a structure used for file io. Search through the usual header files such as "stdio.h", "stdlib.h" for the definition.
Remember that pointer just means address.

Comment: While `char` is often signed, its signedness is implementation-dependent.